# Make a SQL Server script compile including a column that doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL script that's run as a migration on a database before a column is dropped. It works fine the first time because the source column exists, but it fails if you try to run the migration again, because now the column doesn't exist. I wrapped it in an IF, so the statement is only run if the column does exist, but it still needs to be able to compile that bit, even though I know it won't run it.

Here's a simplified version:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'SourceColumn') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableB
    SET DestColumn = TableA.SourceColumn
    FROM TableB
    JOIN TableA AS ON TableB.AId = TableA.Id
    WHERE TableB.DestColumn != TableA.SourceColumn;
END

ALTER TABLE TableA 
DROP COLUMN SourceColumn;
```

Comment: `exec('UPDATE TableB ......WHERE TableB.DestColumn != TableA.SourceColumn;');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is dynamic SQL:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'SourceColumn') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
UPDATE TableB
    SET DestColumn = TableA.SourceColumn
FROM TableB JOIN
     TableA 
     ON TableB.AId = TableA.Id
WHERE TableB.DestColumn <> TableA.SourceColumn';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

You could also use a fun hack to solve this and not use dynamic SQL . . . assuming that `id` is a primary key:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TableA', 'SourceColumn') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableB
    SET DestColumn = a.SourceColumn
    FROM TableB JOIN
         (SELECT a.id,
                 (SELECT SourceColumn   -- NO ALIAS!!
                  FROM TableA a2
                  WHERE a2.id = a.id
                 ) as SourceColumn
          FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN
               (VALUES (NULL)) v(SourceColumn)
         ) a
         ON TableB.AId = a.Id
    WHERE TableB.DestColumn <> TableA.SourceColumn;
END;
```

How does this work?  It uses scoping rules to assign the value of `SourceColumn` in the subquery.  If the column is in `TableA`, then it is filled in.  If not, it is filled in with the value from `v`.  However, that doesn't matter because the code won't be run in that case.  The only purpose is to avoid the identifier error.